# Execute a PHP function after clicking on sweetalert popup button

Tags: javascript, php, sweetalert

This is my JavaScript function that opens a sweet alert pop up with two buttons (yes and no) to confirm logout or exit the pop up:

```
<script src="sweetalert2@10.js"></script>
<script>
function alert1() {
  Swal.fire({
    title: 'Logout',
    text: 'Do you want to log out?',
    showConfirmButton: 'true',
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
    showCancelButton: 'true',
    cancelButtonText: 'No',
    confirmButtonColor: '#00e600',
    cancelButtonColor: '#ff0000',
    imageUrl: 'Images/logo.png'
  }) 
}
</script>
```

This is my PHP function:

```
<?php

function logout() {
    setcookie("tem_username", "", time() - 3000, "/");
    setcookie("per_username", "", time() - 3000, "/"); 
}

?>
```

Is there any way I can execute the PHP function after clicking on the yes button on the sweet alert pop up?

Comment: Javascript is on client side and PHP is on server side. You will have to post your data to PHP and return the result. you should look into that fire function

Comment: @MadeInDreams Ok, I figured out how to clear the cookies using java-script but now how do I call the java-script function when I press the yes button on the sweet alert pop up?

Comment: You will have to find the code for the button itself.

Comment: @MadeInDreams Ok, done! Finally I got it working!

Comment: `function alert1() {
  Swal.fire({
  title: 'Logout',
  text: 'Do you want to log out?',
  showConfirmButton: 'true',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
  showCancelButton: 'true',
  cancelButtonText: 'No',
  confirmButtonColor: '#00e600',
  cancelButtonColor: '#ff0000',
  imageUrl: 'Images/coconut.png'
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result) {
      document.cookie = "per_username=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;";
      document.cookie = "tem_username=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;";
      location.reload();
    }
  }); 
  }`

Comment: @MadeInDreams new problem the above code resets the cookies for both yes and no buttons :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTTP Request. For example you can use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios):

```js
axios.get('/set_cookie.php').then(response => { console.log(response)}).catch(err => {console.log(error)})
```

in php file you should just call this:

```php
function logout() {
 setcookie("tem_username", "", time() - 3000, "/");
 setcookie("per_username", "", time() - 3000, "/");
}
logout();
```

Comment: Thanks but I found a completely different solution so I will go with mine